# Asp.net mvc Specified UserAgent no session Id

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, session, iis, redirect

I have a problem with my project Asp.net mvc 1.0, with .net framework 2.0. My application is hosted on a IIS 7.5. My authentication form looks like this:

```
  <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms protection="All" loginUrl="~/Account/LogOn" timeout="60" cookieless="UseUri" />
    </authentication>
    <httpRuntime executionTimeout="1000" maxRequestLength="600000" />
    <sessionState mode="InProc" cookieless="UseUri" timeout="60">
    </sessionState>
```

When a user connects to the webpage, he receives a session id which is stored in the URL. When I connect to my webpage with the default UserAgent (in every browser, Chrome/FF/IE) everything works fine. When I override the browser UserAgent and try to connect with the User agent XXXXXXXX.UP.BROWSER, I receive an infinite redirection loop to address

```
http://<IP>_redir=1
```

But when I connect to the default webpage IIS -  the user agent doesn't matter and everything loads fine, so it must be a problem with the specified UserAgent and my Application. I tried to find any filters for that XXXXXXXX.UP.BROWSER UserAgent but there aren't any. When I studied application lifecycle I tried to find the differences between **good** connection and **wrong** connection and found that functions which are NOT executed are:

```
Application_AcquireRequestState
Application_PostAcquireRequestState
Application_PreRequestHandlerExecute
Application_PostRequestHandlerExecute
Application_ReleaseRequestState
Application_PostReleaseRequestState
Application_UpdateRequestCache
Application_PostUpdateRequestCache
```

and another clue I found is that there is no Session in "wrong" connection - Session object is null.

To sum it up: The connection to my application web page with a specified user agent makes an infinite redirection loop, probably because of the lack of the session ID. What could be the problem ?

EDIT: I discovered that User Agent that contains "UP.Browser" is related to mobile. When I changed cookieless to "UseCookies" everything works. Why option "UseUri" doesn't work for mobiles?

EDIT2 : /admin -> my webpage hosted on specified IP address.
Good connection :[image]

Wrong connection: [image]

Sorry, I don't know how to make these images bigger.

Comment: Can you check that querystring parameters are getting passed or not? You might want to check the URL in network tab if you are using chrome dev tools.

Comment: As querystring parameters, you mean session id in url? Because I don't send any parameters.

Comment: why use cookieless="UseUri" ?

Comment: @Kiquenet sorry, It was 5 years ago, don't know :)

Comment: source code working in your latest apps (ASP.NET MVC) ?

Answer (score 1):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479315.aspx

So you're putting two different values into the URI, one for session and one for forms, which would probably create a lengthy URI:

*"The principal limitation of this feature is the limited amount of data that can be stored in the URL. This feature is not targeted at common browsers such as IE, since these do support cookies and do not require this feature. The browsers that do not support cookies are the ones found on mobile devices (such as phones), and these browsers typically severely limit the size of the URL they support. So, be careful when you use this feature—try to make sure that the cookieless string generated by your application is small."*

My guess is that the key to the infinite redirect loop is this functionality:

```
"// Step 5: We can't detect if cookies are supported or not. So, send a 
//         challenge to the client. We do this by sending a cookie, as
//         well as setting a query string variable, and then doing a 
//         redirect back to this page. On the next request, if cookie
//         comes back, then Step 3 will report that "cookies are 
//         supported". On the other hand, if the next request does not
//         have any cookies, then Step 4 will report "cookies not
//         supported".
SetAutoDetectionCookie();
Redirect(ThisPage + Our_auto_detect_challenge_variable);"
```

Unfortunately, this sounds like a bit of an architecture rethink, as it's probably going to now matter what the full path to your site is and you may have to drop automatic handling of forms authentication.

Comment: How it could be URI length, if it works for with Firefox that have default UserAgent and doesn't work for Firefox with UserAgent UP.Browser? So uri size limitations can not be a reason...

Answer (score 1):

As you said the issue is for mobile browsers, I think this issue is limited to the devices(MOBILE) where the cookies are not supported and the Size of the URL increases and mobile browser severely limit that size, as mentioned in the MSDN reference article above.

Comment: Length is probably not the issue, form id is not generated while loading page. At this moment only session id is provided which is not so long

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to change User Agent containing "UP.Browser" to something else using rewrite rule. Everything works fine ;)

Edit: I found another clue. 
In mobile browser - these with user agents containing "UP.Browser", it was necessary to add slash at the of the address. 
In conclusion:

Everything works fine for user agents not related with "UP.Browser".
User agents containing "UP.Browser" needed address like:

```
http://addr/controller/
```

I don't know why it is necessary. Any ideas?